# How to re-run the feature file if one of it's scenarios failed?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

How to re-run the feature file if one of its scenarios failed?
I'm using Cypress + cucumber.
I was using this
{
"retries": {
"runMode": 2,
"openMode": 2
}
}

but it re-runs just the failed scenario

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add `"retries": 1,` in `cypress.json` file.